# How to enable `read/write` separation to `nodejs mongoose`?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have multiple data centers, and will only allow 1 database for writings, other databases for readings only.

```
+-------------------+---------------------+
| Data center 1     | Data     center 2   |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| App               |    App              |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| dbPaths: {        | dbPaths: {          |
|  w: 'mongodb://1',|   w: 'mongodb://1', |
|  r: 'mongodb://1',|   r: 'mongodb://2'  |
| }                 | }                   |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| R/W locally       |  R locally, Write to the data center 1's db       |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| writable db       | readonly db         |
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

For the app in data center 1, I will configure both writable and readable connections point to data center 1's db; while for the app in data center 2, I will configure writable connection to the data center 1's db, and readonly connections to data center 2's db.

And let `mongoose` to choose the correct connection before doing actions, that is to say:

- insert, save, update, choose the writable connection
- findOne, list, etc, choose the readable connection

### Question:

Didn't see that `choose` feature in official mongoose, is there any good `npm packages` that can do this?